# Problem about finding a Liapunov function, how do I show that it is positive?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following Lyapunov problem, the problem is that I can't prove that $L > 0$ in some neighborhood of $(x_0,0)$ any suggestions I can make?

Set f: $J \subset  \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function $C^{r}(J)$; $r \geq 1$ and $V(x)=\int_{0}^{x}f(u)du$
prove that
$L(x,y) = \frac{1}{2}y^{2}+ (V(x)-V(x_0))$ it is a (non-strict) liapunov function for the following system:
\begin{matrix}
\frac{dx}{dt} = y\\ 
\frac{dy}{dt} = -f(x)
\end{matrix}
In the neighborhood from the stationary point $(x_0,0)$

STEPS:
It is not difficult to prove that it satisfies the condition that $\dot{L}\leq 0$ in any neighborhood of $(x_0,0)$
My problem is trying to prove the condition that $L > 0$ in some neighborhood without the point $(x_0,0)$ being in this $0$, the only thing I know is that $f(x_0) = 0$ and from continuity I thought I could find this neighborhood but I don't know how to justify that $L(x,y) = \frac{1}{2}y^{2}+ \int_{x_0}^{x}f(u)du$ it's positive, Any idea how I can prove this?

Comment: I think you need additional assumptions on $f$. For example for $f(x)=3x^2$ (and $x_0=0$) you get $L(x,y)=y^2/2+x^3$ which takes negative values in each neighborhood  of $(0,0)$: $L(x,0)<0$ for each $x<0$.